# Using Drush how can you see the last user that logged in?

Tags: drush, users

Using drush, how can you see the last user that logged in? What about the last 5, 10, 20?

Answer (score 2):

```
drush sqlq "SELECT name FROM users ORDER BY login DESC LIMIT 10"
```

Tweak LIMIT to change the number returned.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `drush sql-query` to do this:

```
drush sql-query "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY login DESC LIMIT 10"
```

The above will display the 10 latest logins (or less).

If you only want some name you can change the `*` to `name` and you can also change the `LIMIT 10` to the number of results you would like to display.

For example this would return the `name` and `uid` for the last 5 users:

```
drush sql-query "SELECT uid, name FROM users ORDER BY login DESC LIMIT 5"
```

Here is the structure for the `users` table:

```
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field            | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| uid              | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| name             | varchar(60)      | NO   | UNI |         |       |
| pass             | varchar(128)     | NO   |     |         |       |
| mail             | varchar(254)     | YES  | MUL |         |       |
| theme            | varchar(255)     | NO   |     |         |       |
| signature        | varchar(255)     | NO   |     |         |       |
| signature_format | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| created          | int(11)          | NO   | MUL | 0       |       |
| access           | int(11)          | NO   | MUL | 0       |       |
| login            | int(11)          | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| status           | tinyint(4)       | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| timezone         | varchar(32)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| language         | varchar(12)      | NO   |     |         |       |
| picture          | int(11)          | NO   | MUL | 0       |       |
| init             | varchar(254)     | YES  |     |         |       |
| data             | longblob         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Here is an explaination of some of the columns:

- uid - Unique user id
- name - Unique user name
- mail - Users e-mail address
- created - Timestamp for when user was created
- access - Timestamp for previous time user accessed the site
- login - Timestamp for user?s last login
- status -  Whether the user is active(1) or blocked(0)

Comment: darn just beat me to it! =P...  Came up with this: *drush sql-query 'select uid, access, login, name from users order by access desc limit 3 \G'*

Comment: what is the difference from Access and Login table?

Comment: @duckx I assume you're asking about the access and login *fields* rather than tables.  The access field is a timestamp for the last time the user accessed the site (basically, the last time that authenticated user made a request to the server of any kind).  The login field is just what it sounds like: a timestamp of the last time a user logged into the site.

Answer (score 2):

The same functionality for Drupal 8.x+. The users' table is "users_field_data".

```
drush sqlq "SELECT uid,name,mail FROM users_field_data ORDER BY login DESC LIMIT 10"
```